# Powershell: Command will not work with "powershell.exe -command "command"

Tags: powershell, cmd, command, windows-task-scheduler

This Code will work:

```
Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -match 'Ethernet' -or $_.InterfaceDescription -match 'Wireless'}
```

I want start it from Taskscheduler (cmd) or in powershell
This code will not work:

```
Powershell.exe -Command "Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -match 'Ethernet' -or $_.InterfaceDescription -match 'Wireless'}"
```

Error:

- ... etAdapter | Where-Object {.InterfaceDescription -match 'Ethernet'-or  ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.InterfaceDescription:String) [Where-Object], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand

Also as an base64 string same error.

Have anyone an idea why it will not work as an command but direct as command in ps?

Comment: You need to use single-quotes or escape `$` when calling from within PowerShell to evade premature string interpolation: ```Powershell.exe -Command "Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {`$_.InterfaceDescription -match 'Ethernet' -or `$_.InterfaceDescription -match 'Wireless'}"```

Answer (score -1):

```
Powershell.exe -Command "Get-NetAdapter ; Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -match 'Ethernet' -or $_.InterfaceDescription -match 'Wireless'}"
```